# Adding new contact in sugarCRM through PHP script

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am totally new to Sugar CRM. I have a registration module in my website. When someone registers in my site, I need to make new contact of that person in SugarCRM. i have the registration module in PHP. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but it sounds like you're asking how to create a new contact within a logic hook, or something like that.

If that's the case, here's some example code:

```
// Create a new Contacts bean
$newContact = BeanFactory::newBean("Contacts");
// Change values within the bean
$newContact->first_name = "John";
$newContact->last_name = "Doe";
// Write the new contact to the database
$newContact->save();
```

If you're talking about actual users you may instead want the Users module instead of Contacts.

Comment: u can also instantiate a  bean like this `$newContact = new Contacts()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a rest or soap api to get the values from your site and insert it into the contacts module.